# Why does scintilla auto-complete leave start of word

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++, scintilla

I am coding a Notepad++ plug-in to create an IDE for a scripting language that I and some others use.

My problem is that I can't figure out why Scintilla's AutoComplete functionality leaves the start of the string after an AutoComplete selection has been made.

I've tried deleting the start of the string, but this doesn't seem to work either. I suppose I could manually replace the target with the AutoCompletion selection when I get the AutoComplete selection notification, but shouldn't Scintilla do this automagically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `Scintilla.AutoComplete.AutomaticLengthEntered = true`, Scintilla will attempt to guess the length of the word and replace it when the AutoComplete entry has been accepted.

If you're showing a custom AutoComplete list using `Scintilla.AutoComplete.ShowUserList`, the first parameter (`listType`) is the number of characters that will be replaced when a match is accepted.  Similarly, the `lengthEntered` in `Scintilla.AutoComplete.Show` is the number of characters to be replaced.